# Random Articles Within Category WikiMedia API

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api

How would I go about getting a random article within a category using the WikiMedia API?

Documentation on getting a random article can be found [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Random). 
Documentation on getting a list of pages that belong to a given category, ordered by page sort title can be found [here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers).

Comment: Use the API only to get the [categorymembers](https://www.mediawiki.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Manual), and after that randomize them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to get it from the API directly, so your best option is to get members of the category and then randomise on the client or on the server. This is implemented on the [Special:RandomInCategory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:RandomInCategory) page.